# Signature capture in Windows Mobile OS phones?

Tags: windows-mobile

How to capture user signature in Windows Mobile phones. In Windows Phone 7  using inkpresenter we are getting the user signature.

In Windows Mobile, how to  capture user signature?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Inkpresenter is but I'm using Resco controls in my application and I've used an Inkbox control for capturing signatures. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

The InkSerialization demo in [the OpenNETCF.WindowsMobile.Ink project](http://mobileink.codeplex.com/) allows capture.  Since it's Ink, you can then turn around and redispay it on the device or on a PC.